# Access MFF function without Output node mapping

Tags: c#, altova

I need to create a custom MFF method that will take one input and has no output.  The goal of that function is to send some notification over the web that had nothing to do with the output file.  So far when I create function with no return value, the function does not appear in the library, if I add a return value to my function but don't connect this result connection to an output file, the function is not call. Is there a way of doing what I need.